# Why memory prefetch has no impact when transferring from device to host?

Tags: cuda

I have the following setup:

```
constexpr uint32_t N{512};
constexpr uint32_t DATA_SIZE{sizeof(float) * N * N};

__managed__ float ma[N * N];
__managed__ float mb[N * N];
__managed__ float mc[N * N];

__global__ void kernel()
{
  for (uint32_t i{0}; i < N * N; ++i)
  {
    mc[i] = ma[i] + mb[i];
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *[])
{
  for (uint32_t i{0}; i < N * N; ++i)
  {
    ma[i] = 1.0f;
    mb[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  int deviceId{};
  gpuErrchk(cudaGetDevice(&deviceId));
  gpuErrchk(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(ma, DATA_SIZE, deviceId, nullptr));
  gpuErrchk(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(mb, DATA_SIZE, deviceId, nullptr));

  kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
  gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());

  gpuErrchk(cudaMemPrefetchAsync(mc, DATA_SIZE, cudaCpuDeviceId, nullptr));

  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

  float result{0.0f};
  for (uint32_t i{0}; i < N * N; ++i)
  {
    result += mc[i];
  }

  return static_cast<int>(result);
}
```

I compile the code with `03` optimizations. Profiling it with `nvprof ./test` gives me the following (only the memory part):

```
==29300== Unified Memory profiling result:
Device "Quadro P1000 (0)"
   Count  Avg Size  Min Size  Max Size  Total Size  Total Time  Name
       2  1.0000MB  1.0000MB  1.0000MB  2.000000MB  164.9620us  Host To Device
      20  153.60KB  4.0000KB  1.0000MB  3.000000MB  266.0500us  Device To Host
      19         -         -         -           -  551.9440us  Gpu page fault groups
Total CPU Page faults: 9
```

The first line - `HtoD` -  is straightforward - there were 2 prefetches for `ma` and `mb` arrays 1MB each.

The second line is strange for 2 reasons:

1. Prefetching was ignored (well, not completely, more on this later)
2. The total size of the data is 3MB despite the fact that the total array size is 1MB and in `cudaMemPrefetchAsync` also 1MB was specified.

If I run the same code with prefetching commented out I have the following results:

```
==30051== Unified Memory profiling result:
Device "Quadro P1000 (0)"
   Count  Avg Size  Min Size  Max Size  Total Size  Total Time  Name
      20  102.40KB  4.0000KB  508.00KB  2.000000MB  189.9230us  Host To Device
      29  105.93KB  4.0000KB  512.00KB  3.000000MB  278.4960us  Device To Host
      24         -         -         -           -  1.311533ms  Gpu page fault groups
Total CPU Page faults: 14
```

As seen in the table prefetching has an impact on the number of transfers - for `HtoD` it was changed from 2 to 20, and for `DtoH` it changed from 20 to 29. It also has an impact on performance, but that impact is not major. Especially if I compare it with the third variation of the same code, where I use `cudaMalloc` instead of managed memory:

```
    Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
            0.00%  164.80us         2  82.401us  82.209us  82.593us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
            0.00%  81.665us         1  81.665us  81.665us  81.665us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
```

I am running the `NVidia Quadro P1000` laptop, Ubuntu 18.04, Cuda 11.8.

To summarize, here are my questions:

1. Why does prefetch the memory to the host almost have no impact (29 migrations vs 20 migrations)?
2. Why is more memory transferred to the host than requested (3Mb instead of the requested 1MB)?
3. Why even with prefetching the managed memory is the order of magnitude slower than the device memory allocated with `cudaMalloc`?

Comment: The initial location of a managed allocation is unspecified.  Your initialization of `ma` and `mb` at the beginning of `main` are generating CPU page faults - you can easily verify this.  This also accounts for 2 of the 3MB of data that you are asking about.  Try commenting out the first `for`-loop in `main`, and reprofiling.  I think it will instructive.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you. Now I see the relevant part in the documentation. It makes sense and answers all my questions. Could you please repeat your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I don't understand your third question.  It's not clear to me what "performance" you are referring to - whether that is the overall application, or the kernel duration, or the data copy performance. If it is the data copy performance, I don't see "an order of magnitude" difference.  For your two posted data copy numbers (prefetch vs. `cudaMalloc`), the H->D total is almost the same, and the D->H total is about 3x larger, not an order of magnitude.  Anyway, if you understand the answers to your questions (SO frowns on multiple questions per question) perhaps you should answer it yourself.

Comment: In my third question I was referred to the transfer performance. I expected that if change from `cudaMalloc` to `__managed__` and from `cudaMemCpy` to prefetching, I would get the similar performance of the data copying. And I was surprised to see the big difference, not an order of magnitude, like you mentioned, but still very observable 80us -> 266us. Now, as you pointed that the initial location of the managed memory is unspecified, I see that the time increase comes from additional copies DtoH.

Answer (score 1):

As Robert Crovella has mentioned in the comment, the behavior is caused by the fact that the initial location of a managed memory is unspecified.

> By default, the devices of compute capability lower than 6.x allocate
> managed memory directly on the GPU. However, the devices of compute
> capability 6.x and greater do not allocate physical memory when
> calling cudaMallocManaged(): in this case physical memory is populated
> on first touch and may be resident on the CPU or the GPU.

In my case, the memory was allocated on the GPU. That explains why there were 3MB transferred from the device to the host and the number of transfers themselves. If I remove the initialization loop, the number of `HtoD` becomes zero (despite the 2 calls to `cudaMemPrefetchAsync`) and `DtoH` becomes one.